# Wrong material shown in Viewport

Tags: mesh, materials, 3d-view

I have just created a mesh and tried giving it a material which I gave to many other meshes in the same file and now for any reason it is showing the wrong material in Viewport, but the correct material in the Node Editor. If someone has any idea how to solve this problem I appreciate any help.
Thanks for the attention.[image]

Comment: Is the material "Material.002" assigned to mesh faces?

Comment: Umm, I always picked a mesh in object mode and picked material and got done, so I think so. But when I have chosen a single face from the mesh it showed the actual shown material, but it did not help to change it for this one face, it remained white.

Comment: You may be confused about the workings of assigning materials to a mesh , this may be relevant https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh